# Convert dot notation string to object and lookup reference object

Tags: javascript, object, append, assign

I have an dot notated array such as:

```
var base = ['a.b.c','a.e','h'];
```

I also have a reference object:

```
var reference = { 
  a: { 
    b: { 
      c:"Hello", 
      d:"you" 
    }, 
    e:"beautiful",
    f:"and"
  },
  g:"kind",
  h:"World" 
};
```

I need to build an object out of the base notated string and get the values from the reference object. Unfortunately, I cannot change the base nor the reference.

I have it working for each individual part of the array but the problem is when I try to merge the object. It overwrites the value *a.b.c* with *a.e*.

My desired output would be:

```
var desiredOutput = { 
  a: { 
    b: { 
      c:"Hello" 
    }, 
    e:"beautiful" 
  }, 
  h:"World" 
};
```

However, with the code below my output is:

```
var output = { 
    a: { 
        e: "beautiful" 
    },
    h: "World" 
};
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am limited to < ES5 but could use some polyfills such as `Object.assign` if needed.

```
function convert(base,reference) {
    var obj = {};

    var getObjectValue = function(string, reference) {
        var i = 0;
        while (reference && i < string.length) {
            reference = reference[string[i++]];
        }
        return reference;
    };

    for (var n = 0; n < base.length; n++) {    
        var s = base[n].split("."),
            x = obj;

        for(var i = 0; i < s.length-1; i++) {
            x = x[s[i]] = {}; 
        }

        x[s[i]] = getObjectValue(s,reference);
    }
    return obj;
}

var base = ['a.b.c','a.e','h'];

var reference = { 
  a: { 
    b: { 
      c:"Hello", 
      d:"you" 
    }, 
    e:"beautiful",
    f:"and"
  },
  g:"kind",
  h:"World" 
};

var desiredOutput = { 
  a: { 
    b: { 
      c:"Hello" 
    }, 
    e:"beautiful" 
  }, 
  h:"World" 
};

console.log(convert(base,reference));
```

Comment: are you allowed to import some 3rd party modules like lodash?

Comment: no 3rd party lib unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your

```
x = x[s[i]] = {};
```

You're unconditionally overwriting the `s[i]` property even if it's already been populated. Only assign a new object if another object doesn't already exist at that property.

```
if (x[s[i]]) {
  x = x[s[i]];
} else {
  x = x[s[i]] = {};
}
```

```js
function convert(base,reference) {
    var obj = {};

    var getObjectValue = function(string, reference) {
        var i = 0;
        while (reference && i < string.length) {
            reference = reference[string[i++]];
        }
        return reference;
    };

    for (var n = 0; n < base.length; n++) {    
        var s = base[n].split("."),
            x = obj;

        for(var i = 0; i < s.length-1; i++) {
            if (x[s[i]]) {
              x = x[s[i]];
            } else {
              x = x[s[i]] = {};
            }
        }

        x[s[i]] = getObjectValue(s,reference);
    }

    return obj;

}

var base = ['a.b.c','a.e','h'];

var reference = { 
  a: { 
    b: { 
      c:"Hello", 
      d:"you" 
    }, 
    e:"beautiful",
    f:"and"
  },
  g:"kind",
  h:"World" 
};

var desiredOutput = { 
  a: { 
    b: { 
      c:"Hello" 
    }, 
    e:"beautiful" 
  }, 
  h:"World" 
};


console.log(convert(base,reference));
```

This is how I'd approach it:

```js
var base = ['a.b.c','a.e','h'];
var reference = { 
  a: { 
    b: { 
      c:"Hello", 
      d:"you" 
    }, 
    e:"beautiful",
    f:"and"
  },
  g:"kind",
  h:"World" 
};

const results = {};
// Helper function to get the nested value from an array of properties:
const getVal = props => props.reduce((a, b) => a[b], reference);
for (const propStr of base) {
  // Turn string into an array of properties:
  const props = propStr.split('.');
  // Get nested value to assign at the end:
  const val = getVal(props);
  // Get last property to assign on the last object:
  const lastProp = props.pop();
  let obj = results;
  // Iterate through to the nested object on the `results`,
  // creating objects on the way only if they don't exist yet:
  while (props.length) {
    const prop = props.shift();
    if (obj[prop]) obj = obj[prop];
    else {
      obj[prop] = {};
      obj = obj[prop];
    }
  }
  obj[lastProp] = val;
}
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Classic case of looking way too long down the barrel... thank you for pointing out my issue and also providing a nice ES6+ solution. Unfortunately, I cannot use arrow functions as I am working on < ES5. Regardless, you fixed my ugly code and I certainly can adept your ES6 version to work in my environment - Thanks!

Comment: Your ES6 code is not returning the correct result: > Object { b: Object { a: Object { c: "Hello" } }, a: Object { e: "beautiful" }, h: "World" } It adds b to the top instead of under a. Still accept is the answer due to your fix. However, if you could fix your ES6 code or not collapse my original code you have fixed, that would be appreciated ;)

Comment: Oops, need to use `shift` to get the top item in the array, not `.pop`. Given that it's 2020, you really should be writing source code at least in ES2015. If you need to support ancient obsolete browsers that don't understand ES2015 syntax, the tried-and-true professional solution is to use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile the code down to ES5 automatically for production, while keeping the *source* code in clean, concise, readable ES2015+ syntax.

Comment: Cannot agree more - the problem is the system I am working on is using Javascript 1.5 with a self implemented JINT interpreter... it is a well know system used by millions but will bot be updated anytime soon. Using babel will be an option - thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved without while loops!

I've only used es6's Array.prototype.reduce (and semantics, but you can convert/transpile those your self). You can also easily poly/ponyfill it, see [this article](https://reeversedev.com/polyfill-for-foreach-map-filter-reduce).

```js
const base = ['a.b.c', 'a.e', 'h'];

const reference = { 
  a: { 
    b: { 
      c: 'Hello', 
      d: 'you' 
    }, 
    e: 'beautiful',
    f: 'and'
  },
  g: 'kind',
  h: 'World' 
};

const isObject = item => (item && typeof item === 'object' && !Array.isArray(item) && item !== null);

const pick = (obj, keys) => keys.split('.').reduce((prev, key) => {
  const ret = (prev || obj);
  if (isObject(ret) && key in ret) {
    return ret[key];
  }

  return prev;
}, null);

const extend = (target, source) => {
  if (isObject(target) && isObject(source)) {
    Object.keys(source).forEach((key) => {
      if (isObject(source[key])) {
        if (!target[key] || !isObject(target[key])) {
          target[key] = source[key];
        }
        extend(target[key], source[key]);
      } else {
        Object.assign(target, { [key]: source[key] });
      }
    });
  }
  return target || source;
};

const fromDotNotation = (dotNotation, value) => {
  const ret = {};
  dotNotation.split('.').reduce((prev, key, i, self) => {
    return prev[key] = (i === self.length - 1) ? value : prev[key] || {};
  }, ret);

  return ret;
}

const fromDotNotations = (source, dotNotations) => dotNotations.reduce((prev, dotNotation) => {
  return extend(prev, fromDotNotation(dotNotation, pick(source, dotNotation)));
}, {});

const output = fromDotNotations(reference, base);

console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2));
```

In here, we want to be able to build an object from any dot notation, with an initial value at its tail. We'll use a plucking method to pick the initial value from the reference object. Looping over multiple dot notations, we can create an array of constructed objects. simply using a merging method, we can create a target object to which we want to merge our constructed objects into.

Answer (score 1):

I created the following code snippet to get your desired result in simple way using nested foreach, hope this may help you. I described the code in comments.

```js
var reference = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: "Hello",
      d: "you"
    },
    e: "beautiful",
    f: "and"
  },
  g: "kind",
  h: "World"
};

var base = ['a.b.c', 'a.e', 'h'];

var result = {};

base.forEach(str => {

  //split the base by `.`
  var arr = str.split('.');

  //get the value
  var val = arr.reduce((r, el) => r[el], reference);

  //set the initial temporary path of resulting object
  var tmp = result;

  arr.forEach((el, i) => {

    //set final property value into resulting object
    if (i == arr.length - 1)
      return tmp[el] = val;

    //create nested property in resulting object
    if (!tmp[el])
      tmp[el] = {};

    //update temporary path
    tmp = tmp[el];
  });
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
deepLookup(input, targetObj) {
    const nsList = input.split('.');
    let found = targetObj;
    nsList.forEach(ns => {
        if (found.hasOwnProperty(ns)) {
            found = found[ns];
        } else {
            found = null;
        }
    });
    return found;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).